# UpdateItem Dynamodb Boto3 Says Wrong Query

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, botocore

I am trying to increment values of specific columns.
I am using Boto3.

```
update_query = '#clicks.#OS.#os = #clicks.#OS.#os + :inc, #clicks.#Brands.#brand = #clicks.#Brands.#brand + :inc, #clicks.#RAMs.#ram = #clicks.#RAMs.#ram + :inc'
table_urls.update_item(
            Key={
                'urlid': urlid
            },
            UpdateExpression=update_query,
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':inc' : Decimal(1)
            },
            ExpressionAttributeNames={
                "#os"   : os,
                "#brand": brand,
                "#ram"  : ram,
                "#clicks": "clicks",
                "#OS"   : "OS",
                "#Brands": "Brands",
                "#RAMs"  : "RAMs"
            },
            ReturnValues='NONE'
        )
```

Here is Error StackTrace:
Error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: "#clicks", near: "#clicks."
QUERY::>> #clicks.#OS.#os = #clicks.#OS.#os + :inc, #clicks.#Brands.#brand = #clicks.#Brands.#brand + :inc, #clicks.#RAMs.#ram = #clicks.#RAMs.#ram + :inc
```

Comment: you need to add **SET** at the start of your update query string, as in `update_query= "SET #clicks.#OS.#os ..."`

Comment: @neilharia7 That's correct, please add that as an answer instead of a comment so I can upvote it :-)

Comment: Sure, @Maurice will add it.

Comment: Yes I figured it out later.. after 1hr XD. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `SET` at the start of the update_query string. Everything rest seems proper.

```
update_query = 'SET #clicks.#OS.#os = #clicks.#OS.#os + :inc, #clicks.#Brands.#brand = #clicks.#Brands.#brand + :inc, #clicks.#RAMs.#ram = #clicks.#RAMs.#ram + :inc'
table_urls.update_item(
            Key={
                'urlid': urlid
            },
            UpdateExpression=update_query,
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':inc' : Decimal(1)
            },
            ExpressionAttributeNames={
                "#os"   : os,
                "#brand": brand,
                "#ram"  : ram,
                "#clicks": "clicks",
                "#OS"   : "OS",
                "#Brands": "Brands",
                "#RAMs"  : "RAMs"
            },
            ReturnValues='NONE'
        )
```